# Find random state of sklearn decision tree classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have some data that I'm fitting an `sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier` to.  Because the classifier uses a bit of randomness I run it several times and save the best model.  However I want to be able to re-train the data and get the same results on a different machine.

Is there a way to find out what was the initial `random_state` after I train the model for each classifier?

**EDIT** The `sklearn` models have a method called `get_params()` that shows what the inputs were.  But for `random_state` it still says `None`.  However according to the documentation when that's the case it uses `numpy` to produce a random number.  I'm trying to figure out what that random number was

Comment: The online docs indicate that the default `random_state` is `None` so this would appear to be correct see this:http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Comment: I know that that is the default use, what I'm asking is when I use `random_state=None` and I fit the model, after fitting is there a way to find out what the result of `numpy.random` was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass an explicit random state to the d-tree constructor:

```
>>> DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42).get_params()['random_state']
42
```

Leaving it at the default value of `None` means that the `fit` method will use `numpy.random`'s singleton random state, which is not predictable and not the same across runs.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't word my question correctly.  What I'm wondering is if I used `random_state=None`, and it uses `numpy.random` as it should, is there a way to find out after the model is fit to learn what the result from `numpy.random` was?

Comment: @sedavidw: in that case, the answer is "that's impossible".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you are potentially better off using a Random Forest for this purpose - Random Forests contain a number of trees modelled on subsets of your predictors.
Then, you are able to see the random_states that have been used in the model by simply using `RandomForestVariableName.estimators_`

I'll use my code as an example here:

```
with open('C:\Users\Saskia Hill\Desktop\Exported\FinalSpreadsheet.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    titanic_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    row = titanic_reader.next()
    feature_names = np.array(row)

    # Load dataset, and target classes
    titanic_X, titanic_y = [], []
    for row in titanic_reader:  
    titanic_X.append(row)
    titanic_y.append(row[11]) # The target values are your class labels

    titanic_X = np.array(titanic_X)
    titanic_y = np.array(titanic_y)
    print titanic_X, titanic_y

print feature_names, titanic_X[0], titanic_y[0]
titanic_X = titanic_X[:, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]] #these are your predictors/ features
feature_names = feature_names[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

from sklearn import tree

rfclf = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', min_samples_leaf=1,  max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None, verbose=0)

rfclf = rfclf.fit(titanic_X,titanic_y)

rfclf.estimators_     #the output for this is pasted below:

[DecisionTreeClassifier(compute_importances=None, criterion='entropy',
        max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
        random_state=1490702865, splitter='best'),
DecisionTreeClassifier(compute_importances=None, criterion='entropy',
        max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_density=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
        random_state=174216030, splitter='best') ......
```

Random Forests thus introduce randomness into the Decision Tree files, and require no adjustment from the initial data used by the Decision Tree, but they act as a method of cross-validation supplying you with more confidence in the accuracy of your data (particularly if, like me, you have a small dataset).